# After the migration of SLA's in D365, on Hold time is not working

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

After the migration of **SLA's in D365**, on Hold time is not working and is empty.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is about software development. How is your question related to programming?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen the question is related to Dynamics365 which is the tag being used. This does not require coding skills but it does require power platform development skills. I think the question can be improved, but I don't believe it to be too out of scope based on other questions I've seen under this tag.

Comment: I'm afraid your post is off-topic. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Hi Vinay, I think the best approach to your scenario is to raise a support ticket with Microsoft. There's not much that we can do with the details you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

[SLA Active Duration and elapsed time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-case-sla#view-active-duration-and-elapsed-time-for-sla-kpi-instances)

In UCI-SLA, we have “Elapsed time” to track onHold duration and “Active Duration” to track active duration of that SLAKPI instance. We cannot do this on case entity level as one case can have multiple KPIs with different pause conditions and each SLA KPI instance may have different calendar associated with it.

In Legacy SLA "last onHold time" and "onHold Duration" is populated as it doesn’t support pause conditions at SLA item/SLA KPI level which is supported in UCI-SLA (that’s why, for UCI-SLA customers should not use “onholdtime” to determine onHold duration for SLA KPI instance.)